# finding out what is the range with Endxl

Tags: excel, vba

First get the range of non-empty cells from Source workbook. Then select similar range of cells in Destination Workbook. How can this be achieved?

Full Code::

~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Public Sub ConvertTo_K()

Dim rng1 As Range 

Dim rng2 As Range 

Set rng1 = Workbooks("Source.xls").Worksheets("Source").Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Resize(, 1)) 

Set rng2 = Workbooks("Destination.xls").Worksheets("Destination").Range(rng1.Address)

rng2.Value = Round(rng1.Value / 1000, 2)

 'At this point, an error message of Type Mismatch pops up (Due to different ranges of rng1 and rng2). Do i have to use a loop? How to do that? 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Round(rng1.Value / 1000, 2)` will not work because rng1 is a collection of ranges and can be accessed by `rng1.Cells(1).value`

`rng1.Value` is not valid.

You may loop thru each cell of rng2 and apply the round formula.

```
Public Sub ConvertTo_K()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim RoundRange As Range
    Dim rngVal As Double

    Dim SourceWkb As Workbook
    Set SourceWkb = Workbooks("Source.xls")

    Dim SourceSht As Worksheet
    Set SourceSht = SourceWkb.Worksheets("Source")

    With SourceSht
     Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Resize(, 1))
    End With

    Dim DestinWkb As Workbook
    Set DestinWkb = ThisWorkbook  'Workbooks("Destination.xls")

    Dim DestinSht As Worksheet
    Set DestinSht = DestinWkb.Worksheets("Destination")

    With DestinSht
          Set rng2 = .Range(rng1.Address)
    End With

     'rng2.Value = Round(rng1.Value / 1000, 2) This wont work

     rng1.Copy rng2

     For Each cell In rng2
        cell.Value = Round(cell / 1000, 2)
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, @Santosh! It works are expected. Just one question, if my Destination range needs to be other than the source range, then how can we do it? I dont want to copy the rounded values in "A2: till end" of Destination.xls, rather in "C7:till end". How can we get to know the complete range of source(rng1)? If I make Set rng2 = .Range("C7"), then only first value will be rounded off, others will just be copied. How to get the rounded values for all? Please put some light on this also.

Comment: @vbastart Please have a look at FormulaR1C1

Comment: I have gone thro' the net to get usage of FormulaR1C1, but does not seem to get a hold of it. In my code, how should I be using it so that all the values will be copied and rounded off? I am really not sure how to do this. I tried like,
Set DestinationRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R7C9", but get an error of Object is required.!! :(

Comment: FormulaR1C1 does not help here. I have found a way to do that as follows:
Set DestinationRng = .Range("C9:C" & (8 + SourceRng.Rows.Count))
It works perfect with this!!

Answer (score 0):

If your `rng1` works fine you could do it this way:

```
set rng2 = Workbooks("Destination.xls").Worksheets("Destination").Range(rng1.address)
```

Comment: Thanx. My actual code goes like (See the edited section): I need to consider a range of values from Source sheet,round them off to nearest 1000 & then copy into Destination sheet,but I get an error of type mismatch (due to diff ranges of rng1 and rng2). Do I have to use a loop, if yes, then how? Any help would be appreciated.